# arabic data issue with mysqli charecter set

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to convert the latin character set mysql data to actual arabic data (utf8) in php ?

Arabic data - مشكلةمشكلةمشكلة
In Data base - Ø§Ù„ØµÙÙ‚Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ…ÙŠØ© 
Mysql charecter set - latin

I want to convert the "Ø§Ù„ØµÙÙ‚Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„ÙŠÙˆÙ…ÙŠØ©" to someting like "مشكلةمشكلةمشكلة" for sending it to the pdf library .

Is there any way with out changing the mysql character set ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the character set of that particular column  to utf8_general_ci.

Comment: i dnt want to change the character set of my data base only want to convert the lantin character set data to correct data in PHP ... is there any way ?

Comment: You don't need to change character set of entire db only you need to change set of that particular column. And if you have done that in php , at time of insertion to db mysql wont understand that characters so you should need to change character set column...